# cannot be resolved or is not a field Android

Tags: java, android

I have checked similar question on StackOverflow but I couldn't find a solution that solves my problem. My strings.xml :

```
<string name="true_button">True</string>
<string name="false_button">False</string>
```

My Activity Java :

```
private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
}
```

I get **cannot be resolved or is not a field**  for **R.id.true_button** and **R.id.false_button**

I can see those variables in R.java file. Can you tell me how to fix these errors? Thanks.

Comment: _"I can see those variables in R.java file."_ Those variables in `R.java` should be in the static class `string`, not `id`.

Comment: Do you have a pair of Buttons in your layout named like the strings? `I can see those variables in R.java file.` You better leave that file **closed**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tryng to cast string field to a Button object !!!!!! its impossible !!!
you must declare they buttons in your layout like this sample :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="True" />
```

Answer (score 2):

With this code:

```
mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
```

you are trying to get two buttons from your activity_quiz layout with IDs true_button and false_button. Check activity_quiz.xml file and see if you have declared these two buttons with these IDs.

To recall String resources you have to use R.string instead of R.id.